# Is there any way to parallelize ggplot plotting? [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, parallel-processing

I'm working with very big datasets (2M) that make very slow the process of plotting with ggplot... anyone knows if there is any way to parallelize ggplot plotting? (sorry for not writing any code, I've not idea of possible solutions...). Thanks!

Comment: Can't speak to speeding up the actual process, but what's the rationale in plotting every datapoint?  Seems it would make sense to summarise huge datasets before plotting.

Comment: i like the question if it is possible, but i don't think it is. Also i don't have any prove either. But in general you should prepare your data before plotting. GGplot is kinda forgiving, but other use cases got a lot of problems with plotting to much data points. In `matplotlib` from python for example, you normaly just plot every nth. value if your data is to large. If you got millions of data, it does not matter anyway

Comment: Hi, not sure about paralleled plotting. When I plot big data-sets, I work with a subset first (eg the first 10,000, or a random 10,000).  `... %>% slice(1:10000) %>% ...`

Comment: If it is points then you can consider using https://github.com/exaexa/scattermore package. It does not output points but instead draw an image with all points on it and return the image

Comment: Thanks all of you, guys. Finally I used the package commented by @Billy34... very useful! Thanks a lot!